# How do I tell which Minecraft Bedrock mods can (or should) be deployed to server vs. the client?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have a Bedrock server set up for my family and they access it through through their respective iPads.

As I've been tinkering with various Bedrock mods, it seems that some mods work just fine when deployed to the server -- i.e. everyone who visits the server can take advantage of it ([example](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft-bedrock/addons/faithful-64x-bedrock)). Most of the other mods don't seem to have any effect when deployed to the server -- i.e. the kids visit the server, but nothing is different ([example](https://mc-addons.com/mods/mods-120/1896-modern-furniture-survival-addon.html)). In the latter case, the mods seem to work just fine if deployed on the client side (for solo play).

The most troubling thing is that the descriptions of the mods don't seem to indicate which is which, so it's a lot of time-consuming trial and error. And the documentation/guides I've found online are very lacking. I can only guess there's some detail I'm overlooking.

Is there a way to tell which mods work on the server vs. the client? So far, it **seems** like mods that alter textures work just fine on the server, but mods that add content, items, etc. do not.